# How can i add Day and Night Mode to AepubReader in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, epub

currently iam using AepubReader for reading epub files,But i want to implement day and night mode in that?Do you know how can i implement that modes? 
Currently iam using following code but the problems are

1.Night mode is only effecting a particular chapter.
2.Day mode changes font the color to black.

```
 NSUserDefaults *userDefaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  [userDefaults2 setBool:NO forKey:@"cc"];
  [userDefaults2 synchronize];

  [webView setOpaque:NO];
  [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
  //    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
  //    {
  NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'white'"];

  [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
  //    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me

```
-(IBAction)night:(id)sender{

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults2 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults2 setBool:NO forKey:@"btnM1"];
[userDefaults2 synchronize];

[_webview setOpaque:NO];
[_webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'white'"];
[_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];}

-(IBAction)day:(id)sender{

NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setBool:YES forKey:@"btnM1"];
[userDefaults synchronize];

[_webview setOpaque:NO];
[_webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
NSString *jsString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'black'"];
[_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString2];}





- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
NSUserDefaults *menuUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if([menuUserDefaults boolForKey:@"btnM1"]){
    [_webview setOpaque:NO];
    [_webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    NSString *jsString2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'black'"];
    [_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString2];

}

else{
    [_webview setOpaque:NO];
    [_webview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextFillColor= 'white'"];
    [_webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];

}}
```

Comment: Did u use swipping or something??@ASHINI

Comment: "document.getElementsByTagName('body')" this line means it will select one html(chapter body for day and night mode so you never get a complete day and night mode

Comment: Yes, I am using swipe. Try this project [link](https://github.com/zeroCoder1/Epub-Reader)

Comment: Ashini :It a vertical scrolling epub reader ryt?? Do you have any idea about how can i add bookmark ?

Comment: Yes, its a vertical scrolling epub. Add bookmarks by adding current page index to an array.'- (IBAction)bookmark:(id)sender {
    bookmarkFlag=YES;
    [BookmarkArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentpage+1]];
    for (int i=0; i < [BookmarkArray count]; i++ ) {
        for (int j=(i+1); j < [BookmarkArray count]; j++) {
            if ([[BookmarkArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:[BookmarkArray
                                                       objectAtIndex:j]]) {
                [BookmarkArray removeObjectAtIndex:j];
            }
        }}
 }'

Comment: I think you forget one thing about epub the main feature of epub "ITS A FREE FLOW TEXT FORMAT " your bookmark method is not following the epub feature because of that reader.I think you should use AEpubReader

Comment: epub reader : [link](http://ideveloperworld.blogspot.in/2011/02/epub-reader.html) [link](https://github.com/Aquaware/ePubReader)[link](https://github.com/st3fan/iphone-bookreader/tree/master/Sources/Application)

Comment: Do you have any idea about how can i parse toc.ncx/toc.xhtml file and list in hierarchy.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003773   use nsxml parser for that

Comment: i can parse the file succesfully, but i am facing trouble while getting the hierarchical view in UITableview like ibooks.

Comment: One more thing are you able to get the first line sentence from ur uiwebview throught js?

Answer (score 0):

- You can use this code also for day & night mode. This code may be
  work for as your need.
- This will properly work for `UIWebView`.

The code is:

```
BOOL isNightMode;

- (IBAction)nightModeBtn_click:(id)sender {
    isNightMode = YES;
    [self.webView reload];
}
- (IBAction)dayModeBtn_click:(id)sender {
    isNightMode = NO;
    [self.webView reload];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)_webView{
  if(isNightMode == YES){
    [self.webView setOpaque:NO];
    NSString *setJavaScript = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitFilter='grayscale(100%%)';document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].style.webkitFilter='grayscale(100%%)'; DOMReady();"];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setJavaScript];
  }
}
```